# Inject request into Symfony2 Entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 project and today I'm asked to make it internationalized.

I have several MySQL entities and the new translated contents that I would like to put in a single table containing:

```
ID | language | content_key | content_translation
```

Once the _locale is set, I would like to be able to pass this at Entity level, in order to make the Model layer retrieve the content itselves (making a second call to the translation table if that content is one of the translatable one).

I've tried to use Translatable Extension, but since it is a pre-existing database and project, it is not an easy way to pursue.

How can I inject the request (or pass the _locale only) to my Entities?

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Doctrine as ORM with Symfony2?

Then have a look at the [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions). This bundle provides different new behaviors for your entities. 
It has also a [translatable behavior](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) which is really powerfull.

Integrating the doctrine extensions in Symfony2 [is not so complicated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html).

If you can't use the Doctrine Extensions with your Code/Database, i would try the [Doctrine Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) to develop the translatable behavior of your own.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've already tried it, but - since is a pre-existing database - it is not easy to integrate it with the translatable behavior: I asked to the extensions developer support in order to have more info, and they said me that I should do something custom because there is no migration procedure with the extension. In alternative, I could try to make a brand new project, use the extension and then try to apply it to my project. Thanks a lot PatrickD

Comment: Once i used the Doctrine Extension for a preexisting database. It was an old legacy code base and a complete rewrite with symfony, but this really depends heavily on your use case. I updated my answer with a hint for another possibility to develop this functionality of your own.